# Detect and remove prev/next arrows if there's more than one image

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a slideshow HTML that's generated with 3 images and shown are the `Prev <<` and `Next >>` buttons.

```
<div class="wp-block-gallery">
    <div class="wpcookie-slide"> 
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="image1.jpg" alt="image"> 
    </div>
    <div class="wpcookie-slide"> 
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="image2.jpg" alt="image"> 
    </div>
    <div class="wpcookie-slide"> 
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="image3.jpg" alt="image">
    </div>
    <span class="wpcookie-controls wpcookie-left-arrow"> << Prev </span> 
    <span class="wpcookie-controls wpcookie-right-arrow"> Next >> </span> 
</div>
```

I want to hide the `<< Prev` & `Next >>` buttons when there's just 1 image in the slideshow. It creates a bad UX for the users to show the arrows when there's only 1 image  in the slideshow.

Here's the JS code that generates the slideshow:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".wp-block-gallery")?.forEach( slider => {
    var src = [];
    var alt = [];
    var img = slider.querySelectorAll("img");
    /*Code by MKS Starts */
    var singleImage = img.length === 1; 
    var leftArrow = document.querySelector('.wpcookie-controls.wpcookie-left-arrow'); 
    var rightArrow = document.querySelector('.wpcookie-controls.wpcookie-right-arrow'); 
    rightArrow.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    leftArrow.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    /*Code by MKS Ends*/
    img.forEach( e => { src.push(e.src);   if (e.alt) { alt.push(e.alt); } else { alt.push("image"); } })
    let i = 0;
    let image = "";
    let myDot = "";
    src.forEach ( e => { image = image + `<div class="wpcookie-slide" > <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="${src[i]}" alt="${alt[i]}" > </div>`; i++ })
    i = 0;
    src.forEach ( e => { myDot = myDot + `<span class="wp-dot"></span>`; i++ })
    let dotDisply = "none";
    if (slider.classList.contains("dot")) dotDisply = "block";    
    const main = `<div class="wp-block-gallery">${image}<span class="wpcookie-controls wpcookie-left-arrow"  > << Prev </span> <span class="wpcookie-controls wpcookie-right-arrow" > Next >> </span> <div class="dots-con" style="display: ${dotDisply}"> ${myDot}</div></div> `       
    slider.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",main  );
    slider.remove();
})

document.querySelectorAll(".wp-block-gallery")?.forEach( slider => { 
var slides = slider.querySelectorAll(".wpcookie-slide");
var dots = slider.querySelectorAll(".wp-dot");
var index = 0;

slider.addEventListener("click", e => {if(e.target.classList.contains("wpcookie-left-arrow")) { prevSlide(-1)} } )
slider.addEventListener("click", e => {if(e.target.classList.contains("wpcookie-right-arrow")) { nextSlide(1)} } )
function prevSlide(n){
  index+=n;
  console.log("prevSlide is called");
  changeSlide();
}
function nextSlide(n){
  index+=n;
  changeSlide();
}
changeSlide();
function changeSlide(){   
  if(index>slides.length-1)
    index=0;  
  if(index<0)
    index=slides.length-1;  
    for(let i=0;i<slides.length;i++){
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
      dots[i].classList.remove("wpcookie-slider-active");      
    }
    slides[index].style.display = "block";
    dots[index].classList.add("wpcookie-slider-active");
}
 } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your HTML is accurate to your particular situation, then CSS could achieve this; explanatory comments are in the code below:

```css
/* generic reset, and removal of (some) browser defaults */
*,::before,::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* ensuring the <HTML> element takes all availble space on
   the block (vertical, in most European languages) axis: */
html {
  block-size: 100%;
}

/* setting the <body> to take all of the dynamic viewport
   block size (1dvb is equivalent to 1vh or 1% of the
   vertical space, in left-to-right, top-to-bottom languages): */
body {
  block-size: 100dvb;
}

main {
  /* setting the size of the <main> element along its inline-
     axis to 80dvi (dynamic viewport inline size), with an
     absolute minimum size of 20rem and maximum size of 1200px: */
  inline-size: clamp(20rem, 80dvi, 1200px);
  /* margin auto on the inline axis: */
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.wp-block-gallery {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.wpcookie-controls {
  align-self: stretch;
  background-color: lavenderblush;
  display: grid;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* I've made this partially transparent for purposes of the
     demo, but in production "opacity: 0" or "display: none"
     may be preferable: */
  opacity: 0.4;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  place-content: center;
}

.wpcookie-left-arrow {
  border-radius: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
  /* moving the element to the first position of the layout order,
     without rearranging the DOM: */
  order: -1;
}

.wpcookie-right-arrow {
  border-radius: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
}

/* here we're selecting all .wpcookie-controls elements that follow
   a .wpcookie-slide element tha itself follows a previous
   .wpcookie-slide element, using the general sibling combinator
   (the '~' character, the 'tilde'): */
.wpcookie-slide ~ .wpcookie-slide ~ .wpcookie-controls {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- the <main> is irrelevant to the demo, it just made it easier to inspect
     and copy the html in JS Fiddle: -->
<main>
    <div class="wp-block-gallery">
      <div class="wpcookie-slide">
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="//picsum.photos/id/10/100/200" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="wpcookie-slide">
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="//picsum.photos/id/20/100/200" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="wpcookie-slide">
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="//picsum.photos/id/30/100/200" alt="image">
      </div>
      <span class="wpcookie-controls wpcookie-left-arrow">«Prev</span>
      <span class="wpcookie-controls wpcookie-right-arrow">Next »</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="wp-block-gallery">
      <div class="wpcookie-slide">
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="//picsum.photos/id/40/100/200" alt="image">
      </div>
      <!-- please note the change of '<<' to the &laquo; entity, because
           "<" characters must be escaped in HTML, otherwise the browser
           (and prettifying scripts) can get confused about whether there's
           a new element, and since there's an actual character that can be
           used I prefer to use it: -->
      <span class="wpcookie-controls wpcookie-left-arrow">
        « Prev </span>
      <!-- it's unnecessary to escape the ">" characters, but for the
           purpose of 'balance' and continuity, and because there's a
           specific character available, I also replaced the ">>" with
           the &raquo; character entity: -->
      <span class="wpcookie-controls wpcookie-right-arrow"> Next &raquo; </span>
    </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2sn0beq5/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self).
  - [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color).
  - [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
  - [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).
  - [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
  - [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).
  - [CSS Logical Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_logical_properties)
  - [CSS Relative Length Units (`dvb`, `dvi`, etc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#relative_length_units).
  - [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
  - [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
  - [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
  - [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
  - [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
  - [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
  - [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).
  - [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).
  - [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
  - [`place-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content).
    HTML:
  - "[HTML Living Standard: Named Character References](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#named-character-references)."

Comment: I don't understand how opacity will solve this problem. Am I missing something? I didn't post the css code here since I want the entire element to go away using opacity: 0 or display: none. However, I'll need JS code to detect if there's 1 image or 2+ images.

Comment: If you read the comments in the CSS, it clearly says: "*I've made this partially transparent for purposes of the demo, but in production `opacity: 0` or `display: none`  may be preferable*" so, replace `opacity: 0.4` with `display: none` (or any other adjustment you'd prefer to make), see [the revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2sn0beq5/2/). As for needing JavaScript to detect the number of images, no: you don't ***if*** your posted HTML is accurate.

Comment: My God!!! It works but how?! I do not understand even after reading your comments 5+ times in the code. Let me read up more on how `tilde` works. WOW. Thank you so much. This has been bugging me for 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve with your slider. But the way you implemented it looks overly complicated to me. Here is a shorter snippet proving some basic functionality to any number of galleries on the current page. The "prev" and "next" buttons will be hidden for any gallery containing fewer than 2 pictures.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".wp-block-gallery").forEach(gal => {
  const pics = gal.querySelectorAll("div"), n=pics.length;
  let current = 0;
  const show = inc => {
    current = (current+n+inc)%n;
    pics.forEach((p, i) => p.style.display = current == i ? "" : "none");
  }
  gal.addEventListener("click", ev => ev.target.dataset.inc && show(+ev.target.dataset.inc));
  if (n<=1) gal.querySelectorAll(".wpcookie-controls").forEach(el=>el.style.display="none")
  show(0);
})
```

```css
.wpcookie-controls {cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<h2>Gallery 1</h2>
<div class="wp-block-gallery">
    <div class="wpcookie-slide"> 
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/300/200" alt="image"> 
    </div>
    <div class="wpcookie-slide"> 
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/id/102/300/200" alt="image"> 
    </div>
    <div class="wpcookie-slide"> 
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/id/103/300/200" alt="image">
    </div>
    <span class="wpcookie-controls" data-inc="-1"> << Prev </span> 
    <span class="wpcookie-controls" data-inc="1"> Next >> </span> 
</div>
<h2>Gallery 2 (one picture only)</h2>
<div class="wp-block-gallery">
    <div class="wpcookie-slide"> 
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/id/104/300/200" alt="image"> 
    </div>
    <span class="wpcookie-controls" data-inc="-1"> << Prev </span> 
    <span class="wpcookie-controls" data-inc="1"> Next >> </span>     
</div>
<h2>Gallery 3</h2>
<div class="wp-block-gallery">
    <div class="wpcookie-slide"> 
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/id/108/300/200" alt="image"> 
    </div>
    <div class="wpcookie-slide"> 
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/id/106/300/200" alt="image"> 
    </div>
    <div class="wpcookie-slide"> 
        <img decoding="async" loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/id/107/300/200" alt="image">
    </div>
    <span class="wpcookie-controls" data-inc="-1"> << Prev </span> 
    <span class="wpcookie-controls" data-inc="1"> Next >> </span> 
</div>
```

I use *delegated event handling* on each gallery (`gal`). However, the added "click" event will only lead to an action if a `data-inc` attribute exists for the clicked element. In that case the value of that attribute (`ev.target.dataset.inc`) will be interpreted as an increment to be added to the `current` (="to be shown") index.

Comment: Thank You but the JS code converts a WordPress gallery it into a Slideshow. The HTML shown is the generated slideshow code. Hence the complicated part. I simply want to detect if there's more than 1 image in the generated HTML, then to apply a css class `display:none` on both the arrows. So could you please modify your JS code or provide some explanation so I can try it myself? I am no good with JS though. I'm just a HTML/CSS developer.

Comment: PS: I used the 2nd method shown in this article: `https://redpishi.com/wordpress-tutorials/image-slider-in-wordpress-without-plugins/`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time out but I have used the CSS method by David Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the "Prev" and "Next" buttons when there's only one image in the slideshow, you can add a check in your JavaScript code to determine the number of images. If there's only one image, you can either remove the buttons or hide them using CSS.

var singleImage = img.length === 1;

Then grab the html element and update the css.

Comment: That's the idea but I'm unable to put that into code. Applying css code `display: none` is what I'm looking for but I don't know how to go about applying the `img.length === 1`. Thank you.

Comment: var img = slider.querySelectorAll("img"); This returns an array do the check
var singleImage = img.length === 1; next grab the dom events and change the css    var leftArrow = document.querySelector('.wpcookie-controls.wpcookie-left-arrow');
var rightArrow = document.querySelector('.wpcookie-controls.wpcookie-right-arrow'); rightArrow.style.pointerEvents = 'none';cm leftArrow.style.pointerEvents = 'none';

Comment: Let me try your code and revert on this. Thank You so much :)

Comment: Added the code and tried but it's not working. I have very little JS code experience. So added as-is. The console is showing this error: `custom.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')`

Comment: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var leftArrow = document.querySelector('.wpcookie-controls.wpcookie-left-arrow');
    var rightArrow = document.querySelector('.wpcookie-controls.wpcookie-right-arrow');
    if (rightArrow && leftArrow) {
        rightArrow.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        leftArrow.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    }
});